# How to find mx host for multiple email addresses

Tags: email, domain

I have a list of about 100 email addresses that I sent mail to (not spam, invitations to a private memorial service for my best friend). I know that my own email, which is hosted by Network Solutions never receives emails sent from the godaddy domain used to send to the list. Netsol technical support has had an open ticket for several days, no help, not surprising. Godaddy technical support was more helpful in the sense that they actually checked their server logs while I was on the line, and said they could see that the email was put on the wire without a problem. So I would like to find all of the addresses on the list that are hosted by Network Solutions, and contact them by phone, text or email to see if they got the invitation, and if not send it some other way.

The only way I know how to do this is to go to https://mxtoolbox.com/supertool, type in the domain part of the address, and select MX Lookup. Something I can do, but I was hoping for something less labor-intensive just to identify likely problem addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply by querying the dns resolver:

```
~$ nslookup -type=MX google.de
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
google.de   mail exchanger = 0 smtp.google.com
```

Comment: Brilliant, this will be a great help to me! I knew it was "just" a matter of querying DNS, but I didn't know the tool or syntax. Thank you so much!

Comment: So a specific answer for my exact circumstances was just a bash one-liner: : `for f in logs/{*/,}*.log ; do sed -n -e '/@/s/^.*@/@/' -e 's/^@/nslookup -type=MX /p' $f | sort -u | bash | grep netsol; done` I didn't do it as a one-liner of course :-)